# Ember.js new model elem to the first position in the view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, view, model

I have a small action for a message board for posting comments (code below). It's working perfectly but my server side listing is DESC (newest on the top) and this save solution is appending the new model to end of the list. How can I setup the auto insert position? The newsest comment should be on the top.

```
postMsg: function() {
    var msg = this.store.createRecord('msgboard', {
        name:    'name_auto',
        email:   'email_auto',
        ts:      'ts_auto',
        message: this.get('message')
    });
    msg.save();
}
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is instead of directly looping over the array of records you should create a computed property that sorts the records and loop over the computed property. This way even as records are added to the array they would get sorted locally.

For example if you were using an ArrayController and wanted to be able to sort by id you should be able to do something like this.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProp: ['id:desc'],
  sortedMsgBoards: Ember.computed.sort('', 'sortProp')
});
```

and in the template

```
{{#each item in sortedMsgBoards}}
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```